# Is Exception Vector a better name for Interrupt Vector? (in context of ARM)

Tags: exception, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, interrupt

I've understood the difference between an interrupt and an exception but I'm not able to understand the difference between an exception vector and an interrupt vector.
What I found after doing some research is -
Interrupt Vector is the address of an interrupt handler
The location in memory where the exception handler is stored is called the exception vector.
So, they both look identical to me. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Just for being clear: Do you talk about x86? Different architectures could use "interrupt" and "exception" with different meaning.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev. I've edited my question now. I'm asking this in the context of the ARM processor.

Comment: dont get worked up about terminology it is not worth it.  full sized arms (armv7 and older) do not have interrupt vectors, they have addresses where code execution starts (maybe armv8 as well)(the cortex-ms do have an interrupt vector table. so you could maybe call it an exception table).  But the word exception is not all that incorrect even for interrupts as an exception to the normal flow of code execution.  interrupt is the right term as well.   It only really matters when you are searching through the documentation to use their word in that doc to find something.

Comment: Each vendor is correct in their use of terms in their documentation as it is an opinion based thing as to what to call things.

Comment: Interrupt is an exception, exception is not always an interrupt. So, I disagree that you can simple interchange them, @old_timer.

Comment: In both cases they interrupt the flow of the code, ARM is one of the first I know of to try to  separate the terms, the typical terminology you will see in vendor docs is interrupt.  But, again, each vendor is correct in their use of the terms as these terms are broad enough to be opinion based for this use case.  thank you for making my point